# How to perform OTP verification everytime the app is launched?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have created an app using Android Studio and connected it with Firebase.
I am also using Notification service of Firebase, in that I have coded for sending an OTP and then if it is verified, the user is signed in and next activity starts. But the issue is if I have the app installed on my phone and I verify it once by my mobno. and then sign out, the next time I start the app it doesn't ask for OTP verification again and automatically verifies me and signs me in. I want the app to verify(by OTP) the user every time he starts the app. I have followed the code provided at: https://github.com/nihalnova/FirebaseAuth

Comment: Have you correctly signed out?

Comment: Yes, I have finished the ongoing activity and started another activity in my signout code.

Answer (score 0):

OTP only generates ones when you have installed the app and logged into your account after that it knows that its a verified device but i'll suggest just try uninstalling and then try installing it if it asks for it again.

Comment: I want the app to ask again ie. The app should send OTP everytime I start the app.

Comment: Dis you tried uninstalling it and then installing it again

Comment: Yes I did, even after installing and uninstalling, its taking my device as a verified device.